# Basic Geometry: Finding the smallest angle

Tags: geometry

There was someone on Facebook asking this question, I wanted to help, but I'm stuck right know. By the way, here's the question:

> $ABC$ is a triangle in which
>
> $$2\sin(A) = 3\sin(B) = 4\sin(C)$$
>
> Find the measure of the smallest angle

My attempt:

Suppose I set the triangle like this screenshot below (sorry, it's a bit messy):

[image]

Using the sine rule, and dividing three sides with $12$, we have:

$$\frac{\sin(A)}{6} = \frac{\sin(B)}{4} = \frac{\sin(C)}{3}$$

From that, I assume:

$$x=6; \quad y=3; \quad z=4$$

Then, using cosine rule, I have:

$$\cos(A) = \frac{4^2 + 3^3 - 6^2}{2\cdot 4 \cdot 3} = \frac{-11}{24}$$

This is where I'm stuck. Why negative? Did I do something wrong with the assumption or the calculations?

Comment: Not -11/4, -11/24. And minus value of cosine means the angle is bigger than 90deg.

Comment: @Nightflight Thank you. I did input -11/4 on my calculator, got the answer in complex number and turned out it was a typo.

Comment: $C$ is the smallest angle. Now apply cosine rule.

Comment: The smallest side of the triangle will be opposite the smallest of the angles. So the smallest angle will be opposite the side of length $3$, i.e., angle $C$ as ACB has indicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ABC$ is a triangle in which $\bbox[lightgreen]{2\sin(A)=3\sin(B)=4\sin(C)}$.

We will use the fact that $\bbox[lightblue]{\angle{A}+\angle{B}+\angle{C}=180^{0}}$.

Therefore
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
2\sin(B+C)=3\sin(B),\\
3\sin(B)=4\sin(C).\\
\end{array}
\right.
\iff
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
2\sin(B)\cos(C)+2\sin(C)\cos(B)=3\sin(B),\\
3\sin(B)=4\sin(C).\\
\end{array}
\right.
\iff
\\
\iff
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
2\cos(C)+2\sin(C)\cot(B)=3,\\
\sin(C)=\frac{3\sin(B)}{4}.\\
\end{array}
\right.
\iff
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
2\cos(C)+2\sin(C)\cot(B)=3,\\
\sin(C)=\frac{3\sin(B)}{4}.\\
\end{array}
\right.
\iff
\\
\iff
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
2\left(1-\frac{9\sin^{2}(B)}{16}\right)^{0.5}+\frac{6\cos(B)}{4}=3,\\
\sin(C)=\frac{3\sin(B)}{4}.\\
\end{array}
\right.
\iff
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
2\left(\frac{7+9\cos^{2}(B)}{16}\right)^{0.5}+\frac{6\cos(B)}{4}=3,\\
\sin(C)=\frac{3\sin(B)}{4}.\\
\end{array}
\right.
\iff
\\
\iff
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
{(7+9\cos^{2}(B))^{0.5}}+{3\cos(B)}=6,\\
\sin(C)=\frac{3\sin(B)}{4}.\\
\end{array}
\right.
\iff
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
({(7+9\cos^{2}(B))^{0.5}})^{2}=(6-{3\cos(B)})^{2},\\
\sin(C)=\frac{3\sin(B)}{4}.\\
\end{array}
\right.
\iff
\\
\iff
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
{(7+9\cos^{2}(B))}=(36+{9\cos^{2}(B)}-36\cos(B)),\\
\sin(C)=\frac{3\sin(B)}{4}.\\
\end{array}
\right.
\iff
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
\cos(B)=\frac{29}{36},\\
\sin(C)=\frac{3\sin(B)}{4}.\\
\end{array}
\right.
\iff
\\
\iff
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
\cos(B)=\frac{29}{36},\\
\sin(C)=\frac{3(1-\cos^{2}(B))^{0.5}}{4}.\\
\end{array}
\right.
\iff
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
B=\arccos\left(\frac{29}{36}\right)=36^{0},\\
C=\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{455}}{48}\right)=26^{0}.\\
\end{array}
\right.
\implies
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
\angle{B}=36^{0},\\
\angle{C}=26^{0},\\
\angle{A}=118^{0}.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Therefore, $\bbox[lightgreen]{\angle{C}\text{ is the smallest angle}}$.

Good luck!